# Pointwise and uniform convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n-n^n}{n!}x^{n^n}$

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am in deadlock studyibg the pointwise and uniform convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^n-n^n}{n!}x^{n^n}$$

Maybe should I handle it as a power series? But how? Any tips?

Comment: Did you try  d Alembert? I think it works well

Comment: Hint: For $|x|\lt1$, show that $|a_n|\le(2n)^nx^{n^2}$. Then use the $n$th root test.